# Java 9 cant makeConcatWithConstants(Lookup,String,MethodType,String)

Tags: java

I have the following string that I want to use to download the google maps route with `retrofit2`, however it generates the error:

```
symbol:   method makeConcatWithConstants(Lookup,String,MethodType,String)

String requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
                        + "mode=driving&" + "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"
                        + "origin=" + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + ","
                        + mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "&" + "destination="
                        + "13.767152" + "," + "-89.655844" + "&"
                        + "key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_directions_key);

            Log.d("URL", requestUrl);
```

Y need route from google API

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: At a guess, you're trying to compile with a version of Java that doesn't also work with the version of Android you're using.

Comment: symbol:   method makeConcatWithConstants(Lookup,String,MethodType,String)